# Using Android Toolbar

Tags: android, xamarin, android-toolbar

I'm following the following tutorial to implement the toolbar:

http://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-toolbar-goodbye-action-bar/

When I write this code some things cannot be resolved.

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);
    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
    var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar> (Resource.Id.toolbar);
    //Toolbar will now take on default Action Bar characteristics
    SetActionBar (toolbar);
    //You can now use and reference the ActionBar
    ActionBar.Title = "Hello from Toolbar";
}
```

Unresolved things are: base, setContentView, FindViewById, Toolbar, Resource. I cant import them.

Comment: You'll probably have better luck if you mention some where in your post / title / tags that you are working with Xamarin. It's not immediately apparent now unless they follow your tutorial link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first letters of "setContentView", " findViewById" are to be small. The findViewById() method takes arguments like: findViewById(R.id.your_view_name);

And not like findViewById(Resource.Id.your_view_name);

Basically, try changing Resource.Id.your_view to "R.id.your_view". Also, make the first letters of your method names small